# How to block coupling between adjacent waveguides?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, waveguide

I have a number of nonlinear waveguides, say six. I don't want coupling between specific two waveguides. Other than keeping them large distance away, what are the other possibilities to ensure no coupling between the waveguides? Will using a specific material composition of the waveguides help?

Answer (score 1):

Coupling between waveguides occurs, roughly speaking, when one waveguide mode's tail overlaps with another's. To make sure that doesn't happen, you could increase the distance between waveguides, as you suggest. You could also use a different wavelength so that the tail is shorter; or use a different surrounding material in which the tail is shorter.